# What is the Lattice Constant?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

What is a physical description of the lattice constant and how does one calculate it? From what little resources I have found, I have figured out that it has to do with the size of the atoms that comprise the lattice.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you pointed out what part of [the wikipedia article on lattice constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_constant) you find unclear.

Comment: The wiki essentially says that the lattice constant is the distance between the atoms in the primitive lattice. Is this distance edge-to-edge or center-to-center?

Comment: It is the repeat distance(s) of the Bravais lattice. Not all lattices are square, mind you.

Comment: What do you mean by a repeat distance? The question still remains as to if it is edge-edge or not. EDIT: I have found my answer. My problem was one-dimensional. Thank you!